# How to get better RxJava stacktraces with correct Crashlytics error grouping

Tags: android, firebase, rx-java, rx-java2, crashlytics

My target is to:

- Log RxJava chain handled errors to Firebase Crashlytics
- Get some sensible stacktraces (which points also to my code)
- Make Firebase Crashlytics error grouping done right (not all issues grouped to one)

Current setup:

- Add error listener to rxjava `subscribe()` and get throwable
- To get better stacktraces use [RxTracer](https://github.com/halfhp/rxtracer) lib
- Log that throwable to Firebase Crashlytics using `Crashlytics.logException(t)`

Probem with this setup is that Firebase Crashlytics groups almost all errors under RxTracer `TracingObserver.java – line 2 - com.halfhp.rxtracer.TracingObserver.`

I can not find any way to add custom grouping has etc to Firebase Crashlytics

How are you guys reporting RxJava errors to Firebase Crashlytics?

Comment: have a look at this post : https://rongi.github.io/kotlin-blog/rxjava/2017/09/25/breadcrumbs-rxjava-error-handling.html this would probably negate the requirement of the RxTracer library.

Comment: Who could have forseen that stack traces would be useful? Not the creators of RxJava apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57199487/1916449), Crashlytics is grouping issues by the method and line where the root cause exception was created.

`CompositeException` mentioned in the blog post linked above is a nice tool to achieve two things: let your exception be the root cause while retaining the stack trace of the original exception.

```
Crashlytics.logException(CompositeException(throwable, RuntimeException()))
```

The above would group the Crashlytics issues by the place where you put that snippet, because the `RuntimeException` will be the root cause of the logged exception.

A function like this would probably be more useful:

```
import androidx.annotation.Keep
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics
import io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException

class NonFatalException(message: String, cause: Throwable? = null) : RuntimeException(message, cause)

class BreadcrumbException : RuntimeException() {
    override fun getStackTrace() = super.getStackTrace()
            .dropWhile { it.className == "com.example.NonFatalExceptionKt" }
            .toTypedArray()
}

@Keep
fun logNonFatal(message: String, throwable: Throwable) {
    Crashlytics.logException(NonFatalException(message, CompositeException(throwable, BreadcrumbException())))
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
observable
    .doOnError { logNonFatal("Someone stuck in the thermosiphon", it) }
    .subscribe()
```

You'll get reports grouped by the line at which `logNonFatal` was invoked, rather than where root cause of `it` exception was created.